# Why can't the linker find this destructor on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

There is a console application, I write it as part of self-improvement. Sometimes I write in Windows, sometimes in Ubuntu. Until some time there was no problem. Suddenly now with the following settings on Ubuntu, when running:
`g++ AlarmSystem.cpp -o main`, I get this type of error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchydRcW.o: in function `main': AlarmSystem.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `MainConsoleController::MainConsoleController()'
/usr/bin/ld: AlarmSystem.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `MainConsoleController::~MainConsoleController()'
collect2: error: ld
returned 1 exit status
```

**AlarmSystem.cpp**

```
#include "MainConsoleController.h"

int main()
{
    MainConsoleController m = MainConsoleController();
    return 0;
}
```

**MainConsoleController.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MAIN_CONSOLE_CONTROLLER_H
#define MAIN_CONSOLE_CONTROLLER_H
#include <iostream>
#include "MainConsoleView.h"
#include "MainConsole.h"

class MainConsoleController
{
private:
    std::string _currentCommand;

    Commands _command;

    MainConsoleView _view;
    MainConsole _model;

    bool _isWorking;
    

public:
    MainConsoleController();
    virtual ~MainConsoleController();
    void CheckInput();
    void MainLoop();
    void ConvertInput();
    void MakeCommand();
};
#endif
```

**MainConsoleController.cpp**

```
#include "MainConsoleController.h"


MainConsoleController::MainConsoleController()
{
    this->_isWorking = true;

    MainLoop();
}

MainConsoleController::~MainConsoleController()
{

}

void MainConsoleController::CheckInput()
{
    std::cin >> this->_currentCommand;
}

void MainConsoleController::MainLoop()
{
    this->_view.PrintWelcome();

    while (this->_isWorking)
    {
        CheckInput();
        ConvertInput();
        MakeCommand();
    }
}
...
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Tactical note: [Employ the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It doesn't look like `MainConsoleController` needs a destructor. `virtual ~MainConsoleController() = default;` in the declaration should be sufficient

Comment: `g++ AlarmSystem.cpp MainConsoleController.cpp -o main` should work, though it really should be at least `g++ -Wall -Wextra AlarmSystem.cpp MainConsoleController.cpp -o main`

Comment: I usually tack on a `-pedantic` as well

Comment: @user4581301 good tip. Your hint showed me that I have more similar problems. But the error given above corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: @user4581301 `-pedantic`  unfortunately did not help me in anything. I tried before.

Comment: `-pedantic` won't help with this. It tells the g++ compiler to warn you about code that violates the C++ Standard (but is allowed by the g++) and thus reduces portability. And sometimes the extra functionality added by the compiler can lead to... problems. For example, `int array[user_provided_number] = {0};` doesn't do the initializing the Standard requires of `int array[constant_number] = {0};`. Much fun debugging can result.

Comment: @user4581301 Cool, good to know. Haven't read about it before, thanks again.

Comment: @SuperStormer Your hint helped too - more than, actually user4581301 - it solved the whole problem. The only surprising thing is that it used to work without adding any more files, it surprised me that now I suddenly need it. I lost my vigilance. Thanks to both gentlemen, anyway. The tips helped to solve the problem.